# How to sanitize PDFs

Tags: php, security, sanitization

My application allows the user to upload images. Here is how I sanitize the images:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$image = @imagecreatefromstring($file);
imagepng($image, $outputFilename);
```

This protects against:

1. Unintended metadata
2. Attempting to upload non-images as an image

And then I serve this sanitized image to other users.

---

Now I need to do the same thing with PDFs. I want to accept a user-uploaded PDF, sanitize it, store it and then serve it back to users.

Ideally I can use an approach like "print to PDF" on Mac where it keeps the visual aspect of the file but removes any links or active content.

Also if it helps: in my application, nearly all users will be uploading a scanned image file.

It is possible to do this sanitization in PHP with built-in functions?

Comment: I don't think there's anything *built-in*, but there's probably a PDF parser/reader library you can use to at least check whether the file *is* a PDF or not.  There seems to be a PECL library for PDF (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) and I also was able to find https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

Comment: We are also looking for solution to the same problem but somehow ended with nothing. Keep us posted if you found anything